# expected an indented block python error

Tags: python, indentation, python-3.6

I am new to Python so don't know much about it. But I know the basics of indentation and I cannot solve the error of ***expected an indented block*** in the following code.

```
meal =["egg","milk","spam","tomato"]

for item in meal:
    if item =="spam":
        nasty_food =item
        break

if nasty_food:
   print("there is nasty food")
```

Comment: Please attach a source file.

Comment: I can't find any intended error in your code. Recheck your code, make sure you will not mixing up spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visually I don't see an indentation issue in the code you posted. Verify that you are not mixing up tabs and spaces as that can also lead to indentation issues.

Answer (score 1):

You **have** to indent code with **consistency** since that is a must do in Python.

**Don't** use different number of **spaces** for indent per function. This will lead you to new issues.

Try this code:

```
meal = ["egg", "milk", "spam", "tomato"]

for item in meal:
    if item == "spam":
        nasty_food = item
        break

if nasty_food:
    print("there is nasty food")
```

Comment: thanks for your interest, I run your code, but I have the same error

Comment: is this code a part of larger part or is it just this that you are trying to run? Because, I don't have an issue running it.

Comment: ok, it solved
I don't know where is the error, but I rewrite the code again and it works!

Comment: watch out for mixed tabs and spaces. Every decent text editor should have an option to convert tabs to spaces so you do not end up with hard to spot issues like wrong indented code.